# Google Mobile Backend Starter subscribeToCloudMessage error code 400

Tags: java, android, json, google-maps, google-app-engine

I am working on a project using Google's Mobile Backend Starter, whenever I try to set `subscribeToCloudMessage()` on any string other than the string used for broadcasting messages that comes with the starter I get an error.
This code works:

```
CloudCallbackHandler<List<CloudEntity>> broadcastHandler =
new CloudCallbackHandler<List<CloudEntity>>() {
@Override
public void onComplete(List<CloudEntity> results) {
}
};
mCloudBackend.subscribeToCloudMessage(
CloudBackendMessaging.TOPIC_ID_BROADCAST, broadcastHandler);
```

This code does not:

```
CloudCallbackHandler<List<CloudEntity>> handler =
new CloudCallbackHandler<List<CloudEntity>>() {
@Override
public void onComplete(List<CloudEntity> results) {

}
};
mCloudBackend.subscribeToCloudMessage(
"foo", handler);
```

and this is the error
 error:

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 400 Bad Request
 {
   "code": 400,
   "errors": [
     {
       "domain": "global",
       "message": "SubscriptionIDs: String properties must be 500 characters or less.  Instead, use com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Text, which can store strings of any length.",
       "reason": "badRequest"
     }
   ],
   "message": "SubscriptionIDs: String properties must be 500 characters or less.  Instead, use com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Text, which can store strings of any length."
 }
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:111)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:38)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest$1.interceptResponse(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:312)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1042)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:410)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:343)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:460)
    at com.google.cloud.backend.core.CloudBackend.list(CloudBackend.java:314)
    at com.google.cloud.backend.core.CloudBackendAsync.access$8(CloudBackendAsync.java:1)
    at com.google.cloud.backend.core.CloudBackendAsync$9.callBackend(CloudBackendAsync.java:270)
    at com.google.cloud.backend.core.CloudBackendAsync$9.callBackend(CloudBackendAsync.java:1)
    at com.google.cloud.backend.core.CloudBackendAsync$BackendCaller.run(CloudBackendAsync.java:402)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please take a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/22737573/2147383