# Mobile Backend Starter subscribeToCloudMessage will not work

Tags: java, android, json, google-maps, google-app-engine

When I use the subscribeToCloudMessage() function with CloudBackendMessaging.TOPIC_ID_BROADCAST as the topicId as is done in CloudBackendFragment.java everything works fine but when I give this function my own string I get this message:

error:

```
m.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 400 Bad Request

"code": 400,
"errors": [
  {
    "domain": "global",
    "message": "SubscriptionIDs: String properties must be 500 characters or less.  Instead, use com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Text, which can store strings of any length.",
    "reason": "badRequest"
  }
],
"message": "SubscriptionIDs: String properties must be 500 characters or less.  Instead, use com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Text, which can store strings of any length."

at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:111)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:38)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest$1.interceptResponse(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:312)
at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1042)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:410)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:343)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:460)
at com.google.cloud.backend.core.CloudBackend.list(CloudBackend.java:314)
at com.google.cloud.backend.core.CloudBackendAsync.access$8(CloudBackendAsync.java:1)
at com.google.cloud.backend.core.CloudBackendAsync$9.callBackend(CloudBackendAsync.java:270)
at com.google.cloud.backend.core.CloudBackendAsync$9.callBackend(CloudBackendAsync.java:1)
at com.google.cloud.backend.core.CloudBackendAsync$BackendCaller.run(CloudBackendAsync.java:402)
```

Answer (score 5):

This error message means that property `SubscriptionIDs` (you can find it under the `_DeviceSubscription` Kind in your datastore) value exceeds 500 Unicode characters limit. Read [docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/entities?#Java_Properties_and_value_types) for the reference.

From the docs:

> For text strings and unencoded binary data (byte strings), the
>   Datastore supports two value types:
>
> 1. Short strings (up to 500 Unicode characters or bytes) are indexed
>      and can be used in query filter conditions and sort orders.
> 2. Longstrings (up to 1 megabyte) are not indexed and cannot be used in query filters and sort orders.

The reason for this happening is that MBS trying to write all subscriptions into one property.

So to overcome this issue we need to use `Text` instead of `String` type in [MBS backend source code](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/solutions-mobile-backend-starter-java) for the `SubscriptionIDs` property. To do so you need to make following changes in `DeviceSubscription.java` class:

To set `Text` property replace this line of code:

```
deviceSubscription.setProperty(PROPERTY_SUBSCRIPTION_IDS, this.gson.toJson(subscriptions));
```

with this line:

```
deviceSubscription.setProperty(PROPERTY_SUBSCRIPTION_IDS, new Text(this.gson.toJson(subscriptions)));
```

To get `Text` property from the datastore:

1. Replace this line:

   ```
   String subscriptionString = (String) deviceSubscription.getProperty(PROPERTY_SUBSCRIPTION_IDS);
   ```

   with this:

   ```
   Text text = (Text) deviceSubscription.getProperty(PROPERTY_SUBSCRIPTION_IDS);
       String subscriptionString = text.getValue();
   ```
2. Replace this line:

   ```
   String ids = (String) deviceSubscription.getProperty(PROPERTY_SUBSCRIPTION_IDS);
   ```

   with this:

   ```
   Text text = (Text) deviceSubscription.getProperty(PROPERTY_SUBSCRIPTION_IDS);
         String ids = text.getValue();
   ```
3. Replace this line:

   ```
   String[] ids = new Gson().fromJson((String) entity.getProperty(PROPERTY_SUBSCRIPTION_IDS),
               String[].class);
   ```

   with this:

   ```
   Text text = (Text) entity.getProperty(PROPERTY_SUBSCRIPTION_IDS);
           String[] ids = new Gson().fromJson(text.getValue(), String[].class);
   ```

Seems to be valid solution. I have not noticed negative influence on my project so far.

**NOTE:** As docs stated `Text` is **not indexed and cannot be used in query filters and sort orders**. So this limitation could have cause another issues if the property `SubscriptionIDs` required to be indexed.

Comment: Yo probably mean the serverside Code for **DeviceSubstription.java**? Can anybody confirm if this works? I think the problem might be somewhere else (see my other comment). But if not this should be reported as a bug. Or somebody with a working version should send a pull request.

Comment: @r-hold Yes you need to change serverside Code. And this is still works for me. I guess this is a bug.

Answer (score 2):

I went to the cloud.google.com query view and deleted my old device_subscription IDs, thereafter it worked fine. Not sure if you're able to do this.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the subscription ids are being generated using some algorythm that mainly uses the regid that is obtained when you first fire up the mobile backend starter app. To solve this issue when I had it I just called substring on the given regid and shortened it considerably but still left it long enough to guarantee some level of uniqueness.

> private static String doRegister(Context context) {
>        String msg = "";
>        try {
>           GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(context);
>           String regId = gcm.register(Consts.PROJECT_NUMBER).substring(0,16);
>          msg = "Device registered, registration ID=" + regId;

This method is located in the GCMIntentService.java file.
Notice the

> .substring(0,16);

Worked for me! just thought I'd share.

Comment: Thanks, in conjunction with the fix from Julien this worked for me. Have you tried a longer substring? As I see it shouldn't this work up to 499?

Comment: For anyone coming here to find a solution here follow [this](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client) article.

Answer (score 1):

@Juniper's answer makes sense according to the Documentation. 
@jamrockRay's answer didn't work for me.

However i have a feeling that this might be related to the value of the String passed as Entitykind. If i change it from "Guestbook" (as in the example) to something else the error occurs. If i change it back everything works as expected, even with different entity properties. Can you confirm this?

Comment: I can't see any relations between Kind name and this error. The reason for this happening is that MBS trying to write all subscriptions into one property. By default MBS uses only one subscription for GCM that is always less than 500 characters limit. Error occurrs when more then one SubscriptionID trying to write into one property. I guess you've changed not only Kind name "Guestbook" but you've also modified some code which adds additional SubscriptionIDs. For example `Scope.FUTURE` and `Scope.FUTURE_AND_PAST` in your query adding more subscriptions.

Comment: I see your point and its confusing me too. But i have double checked it. I am using the example from the fork with the example prepared for Android Studio https://github.com/thagikura/mobile-backend-starter-android-client-with-AndroidStudio/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/backend/sample/guestbook/GuestbookActivity.java it already uses ''Scope.FUTURE_AND_PAST'' as default. Yes i have modified code in some places, but as soon as i chnage my entitykind name back to "Guestbook" its working again. Will try your solution, as soon as i find time for custom deployment.

Comment: @Juniper i finaly found the time to implement your suggested bugfixed and depoly them. I can confirm: it works for me.

Still confused why changing the KIND_NAME messes things up.

Comment: @r-hold I am having the exact same issue as you with the same backend starter. If I use Guestbook it works, if I use anything else I get the same error. I know I am not doing anything odd when creating the entity as I am using the exact same method just changing the KindName. Very odd