# mobile backend starter listbykind error

Tags: android, mobile, entity, cloud, backend

I am creating a new entity kind in the datastore (named "xyz"), Sending the data works fine. and I see a record created under the new kind on cloud dasboard however, when I try to read it using

```
mProcessingFragment.getCloudBackend().listByKind( "xyz", CloudEntity.PROP_CREATED_AT,     
Order.DESC, 50, Scope.FUTURE_AND_PAST, handler);
```

I get an error saying "SubscriptionIds: String property must be 500 chars or less. My send code is

```
CloudEntity newPost = new CloudEntity("xyz"); newPost.put("message",    
mMessageTxt.getText().toString());
```

As you can see all I have done is replacing "Guestbook" by "xyz", I do not understand why I get the above error. Do I need to change the entity type I subscribe to?

ANy suggestions? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it is too late for this. I had the same problem which I managed to resolve by going to the appspot backend (***.appspot.com) and click the "Clear all query subscriptions".

Initially, it seems that I was unable to change the kindName on the listByKind where I will get the same error like you. However, after clearing the query subscriptions, I was able to change the kindName in the listByKind to anything. I am still about to figure out why this is the case. Perhaps there is a limit on the number of active subscriptions? I will do more testing today.

Anyway, hope this solves your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this thread [Mobile Backend Starter subscribeToCloudMessage will not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22122647/mobile-backend-starter-subscribetocloudmessage-will-not-work)

What worked for me was first clearning all query subscriptions as advised by Pascal on this thread and then doing what jamrockRay suggests, adding

```
.substring(0,16);
```

to this method is located in the GCMIntentService.java file

```
private static String doRegister(Context context) { String msg = ""; 
try { GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(context); 
String regId = gcm.register(Consts.PROJECT_NUMBER).substring(0,16); 
msg = "Device registered, registration ID=" + regId;
```

Worked for me