# Mobile Backend Starter custom kind query returns NullPointerException

Tags: android, mobile, client, backend

I downloaded and ran mobile backend starter sample code by following all the steps required, and yes it worked.

I tried to add a custom Kind (e.g "Person") to the data store, still no problem.

I get the fatal error Whenever I tried to list the "Person" Kind. When i debug the code, It I realized that list(CloudQuery query) method of CloudBackend class doesnt get the "properties" of the custom Kind ("Person").

The same code runs if the kind "Person" replaced with "Guestbook".

Any ideas?

Comment: Please provide code snippets for what you are referring to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you very much for your reply @Drdavidpier.

I finally bypass the problem by deleting my mobile backend project from Google cloud and recreate another mobile backend project. Its working now.

Another issue I noticed is:

```
co.properties.putAll((Map<String, Object>) cd.getProperties());
```

line at `CloudEntity.createCloudEntityFromEntityDto(EntityDto cd)` returns NullpointerException when the `listByKind()` is called. The problem occurs if the table(Kind) has null inserted entities. Deleting null data or inserting non null values only will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Without the code or the error this is difficult to solve but it sounds like you are having the problem described here - [Mobile Backend Starter subscribeToCloudMessage will not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22122647/mobile-backend-starter-subscribetocloudmessage-will-not-work)

The solution that worked for me was Julien's suggestion followed by JamrockJay